# Note as "big white paper" for OSX

Tags: macos, mind-mapping, note-taking

I would like to use a note program for OSX with unlimited zoom in-zoom out but I'm not able to found any.

Like a big white paper with freestlye item adding.

It's like Visio for Windows: I can zoom in and zoom out, take some text and adding images.

Has OSX something like this?

A mind-map tool?

Answer (score 1):

OSX (starting with Lion or Mountain Lion, not sure) has a handy program called Notes that can almost do what you want. It's not white (it's actually yellow), but it can be full screen, which is not bad. You can zoom-in and out to an extent, but if you *really* need zoom, there's always Accessibility mode (though it can get very blurry quite quickly). Needless to say, it's useful once in a while :)

Comment: thanks but it's very-very strict. I would like to add images, free text at any position and in any size.